# How can I retrieve a given number of movies under a given genre using imdbpy?

Tags: python-2.7, imdbpy

I am starting using imdbpy and I am interesting in a way to implement a method with the following specifications:

**Inputs**:

- numberToRetrieve (number of movies to retrive back)
- movieGenre (the genre of movies by example:'horror')

**Output**:

- List of movies object

Many thanks in advance!

Joshua

Answer (score 1):

I'm way too late, but I answer for other user that will need it in the future.

You can do this (not easily, at least).
My best advice is to use the imdbpy2sql.py script to populate a database of your choice (Postgresql, MySQL, SQLite and other) and then script your series of batch operation as SQL statements.  It's possible that you will need to add some indexes here and there to speed-up data retrieving.